# Select specific tables from an SQL data source in Power BI

Tags: sql-server, report, reporting, powerbi

I'm working on setting up PowerBI desktop for a client where they'll import 8 specific tables from a database to work on in Power BI.

However, when I go to import the tables, every table in the database is shown and the specific tables must be selected. There are hundreds of tables imported, and a lot of scrolling to select the correct tables, which leaves room for confusion and error for the clients.

The client accesses the database using windows authentication, and I can't change their settings on SSMS as that would affect how they access data on other applications.

I was wondering if there was an simpler way to save a query in Power BI the users can quickly select when setting up a new report.

Answer (score 2):

You could always use raw sql instead:

[image]

Or select "empty query" and specify it like so:

[image]

Edit: not sure if this is of any help but there's also a filter field:

[image]

Comment: The clients won't know how to use raw SQL unfortunately. Also, is there a way to select multiple tables using the raw sql? I can only seem to be able to select one table with it.

Comment: You could join different tables, but not return multiple tables with a single query as far as I know. Perhaps, you could create a database user for this purpose, and only set permissions to view/access tables you want to be accessible, and let clients authenticate as this user?

Comment: Creating a database user is also not ideal, as the clients databases are set to 'Window Authentication mode' and changing this would require an out of hours server restart I'm not qualified to do and I know my colleagues will want to avoid. I could look into the feasibility of creating Joins but that would make selecting the fields less user friendly as they would all be listed under the one tables instead of seperated. Thank you for clarifying these are my options. Unless there are anymore you can think of?

Comment: There is also an option to filter tables/databases by name - added a screenshot.

Comment: Is it not an option to provide a set of sql queries for your clients to copy and paste?
Possibly you could provide PowerBI reports with all tables/queries specified?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've been looking at my option, and  I think maybe setting up a template on my clients machine with the tables already selected might be the easiest route. That way they can just open the file without having to import directly from the DB themselves. Thanks again!